# regarding recursive deleting of a specific file type

Tags: shell, scripting

I wanted to delete a specific file type say *.bak file from any directory and its subdirectories.

I used the following command to find the files.

```
find <path> -name "*.bak" -type f
```

However, when i tried to do the same, with a condition of only listing the files which are older than 10 days, I am not getting any result:

```
find <path> -name "*.bak" -type f -ctime +10
```

I am wrong at the last part, though not sure what.

Edit: Yes, for now I just want to **find the files with extension bak and older than 10 days within a foler recursively.**

Comment: I don't think there should be the `+` sign in front of `10`

Comment: Still not working with out a + sign. However, I personally have been using this plus sign, no worries.

Comment: So if you want to delete the files, you miss something in the command-line, probably `-delete` switch. Can you describe *what* does not work?

Comment: What do you want to do? delete the files of type `*.bak` or finding `*.bak` files that are older than 10 days?

Comment: updated the question.. As for now, if can find files older than 10 days, of course I can delete them.

Comment: Are you sure that the files have not been modified in any way (content changed, attributes changed, moved, …) in the past 10 days? You say “older than 10 days”, but `-ctime +10` means “the inode was last changed more than 10 days ago”, which is a lot stronger. Give an example of a file that should match and the output of `ls -lc /path/to/the/file.bak`.

Answer (score 1):

`find` ignores any fractional time for `-atime`, `mtime`, `-ctime` and also for the `-*min` counterparts.

So, `-ctime +10` indicates files whose inodes were changed 11 days or before ago.

To get files whose inodes were changed 10 days or more ago:

```
find <path> -name "*.bak" -type f -ctime +9
```

Also if you just want to check the modified time (instead of the inode changing time), you can do:

```
find <path> -name "*.bak" -type f -mtime +9
```

Comment: changing 10 to 9 is not helping either. Since the files are much older than 10 days.. so comparing with 9/10 should be giving the same result.